Trim data in cell to specific format
I have data in column A (example below).



A




0.894.114.695.EE9


1.274.788.355.825


K.S00.001.409.43E



They are unique product codes. They might start with digits (0,1 etc) or letters. They also contains dot, letters and digits.
I need to manipulate this data to format I need i.e. from 0.894.114.695.EE9 to 0894114695 or K.S00.001.409.43E to KS00001409. Basically I have to remove last 3 characters, remove "." and keep 0 in front (if string starts with 0).
Currently to do it I follow the below steps:

=MID(a1,1,13) and overwrite formula (now in row B)
CTRL+F and replace "." with nothing
Then I put formula: =IF(LEN(B2)<10,0&B2,B2)

Is there a possibility of having just 1 formula, that would do all the 3 steps?
I have looked online for solution for weeks, but unfortunately I could not find one, that will work for me.
Thank you in advance for all your help.

Shouldn't this work for you: =TEXTBEFORE(A1,".",-1) and if you want to remove the dots from the output then =SUBSTITUTE(TEXTBEFORE(A1,".",-1),".",)

=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,".",),10). Leading zero's should stay intact?

@JvdV I've changed it slightly and it works as I need it:  =LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",),10)

What about this simple formula:
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2;LEN(B2)-3);".";"")

In order to be sure that the starting zero doesn't get removed, you might start your string with a single quote:

